# React native. I can't find my current location(Geolocation) IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, geolocation, react-native-maps

I need to access my location from GPS. So, i import geolocation to project.

first, I create following like this (install react native map, already link)

and I just already add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in my Xcode

also, I just already libRCTGeolocation.a in my Xcode

then, I just read map view in mapview from Airbnb. tell me to set showUserLocation set it to "true". when set true will ask user to access
location.

reference: https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md

finally, That is not ask anything to access
location. so, I don't know why. I can't find my current location.

and this is my picture step by step that I describe from begin
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7VIk.jpg

I will show you my code.

**Route.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class Route extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        region: {
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }
    };
    this.onRegionChange = this.onRegionChange.bind(this);
}

onRegionChange(region) {
    this.setState({ region });
}

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView style={styles.map}
          mapType="standard"
          showsUserLocation={true}
          followsUserLocation={true}
          showsCompass={false}
          showsPointOfInterest={false}
          region={this.state.region}
          onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
        />
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>
          Latitude: {this.state.region.latitude}{'\n'}
          Longitude: {this.state.region.longitude}{'\n'}
          LatitudeDelta: {this.state.region.latitudeDelta}{'\n'}
          LongitudeDelta: {this.state.region.longitudeDelta}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
        );
    }
}



Route.navigationOptions = { //this define from App.js option in SecondScreen
  title: 'Route', //name top of StackNavigator
};




const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    image: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
    },
    text: {
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    map: {
    width: width,
    height: height*2/3
  }
});
```

Comment: In the iOS simulator it reads a fake location.  Set a custom location using _Debug > Location > Custom Location..._ in the simulator menu.

Comment: But i need to acess my current location from GPS. What should i do?

Comment: If you run it on a real device you will get the real location.  Otherwise you can just put your current location in the menu I mentioned in my previous comment.  You can get your location a number of ways, including this: https://mylocation.org/

Comment: oh, I really thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS simulator it reads a fake location. Set a custom location using *Debug > Location > Custom Location...* in the simulator menu.

If you run it on a real device you will get the real location. If you continue to use the simulator you can just put your current location using the *Custom Location* menu. You can get your location a number of ways, including this: http://mylocation.org/.